How to make gradient merge into navbar instead of "pop" the color changes?
I am trying to make a sticky navbar go into a gradient and then come back to black on it's fixed position, but when it moves it should smoothly merge into a gradient.
When I use the navbar to scroll down and turn from black to a gradient it works but when I go back up it pops into black instead of a smooth transition. how to go about this?
I want the gradient to have the same behavior as when I scroll down but when I scroll back up it dosen't do the same.


window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
  const scrollToTopBtn = document.getElementById("scrollToTopBtn");
  const img = scrollToTopBtn.querySelector("img");

  // Handle navbar background transition
  if (window.pageYOffset > 21) {
    navbar.classList.add("scrolled");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("scrolled");
  }
});
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: 2000px; /* For demonstration purposes */
}
.navbar {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* For Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 21px; /* Sets the navbar 21px from the top */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black; /* Start with a black background */
  transition: background 0.5s ease; /* Smooth transition for background */
  z-index: 1050;
}
.navbar.scrolled {
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 70%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
  ); /* Background gradient on scroll */
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55);
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: #fff; /* Ensure this is white */
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-nav .nav-link.show {
  color: turquoise;
}
.navbar-nav {
  flex-direction: row !important; /* Ensures navbar items are in a row */
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute !important; /* Ensures dropdown opens as an overlay */
}
.nav-link {
  color: white !important; /* Customize color as needed */
}
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* Inline display */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; /* This ensures vertical alignment is centered */
  width: 100%; /* Ensures the navbar takes full width */
}
.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allows items to wrap in smaller screens */
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment */
  justify-content: space-between; /* Horizontal spacing */
  width: 100vw;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: column; /* Stack the links vertically on small screens */
  }
  .nav-link {
    padding: 0px 30px; /* Adjust padding for smaller screens */
    text-align: center; /* Center-align the text */
  }
}
.scroll-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
.scroll-to-top:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
.scroll-to-top img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
}
.scroll-to-top:hover img {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
#scrollToTopBtn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  z-index: 1000; /* Make sure it's above other content */
  outline: none;
}
#scrollToTopBtn img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Navbar Scroll Effect</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
              href="#drawings"
              id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
              role="button"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-expanded="false">
              Drawings
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drawing 1</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drawing 2</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drawing 3</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drawing 4</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drawing 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <button id="scrollToTopBtn" onclick="window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});">
      <img
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Yin_yang.svg/1024px-Yin_yang.svg.png" alt="Go to top" />
    </button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




"When I use the navbar to scroll down and turn from black to a gradient it works" - are you sure about that ...? Doesn't actually look like it to me. Even if I change the transition duration to a larger value like 5 seconds, the change looks instant.

In CSS, you can’t transition a background gradient. It jumps from one gradient to the other immediately, with no smooth transition between the two. https://css-tricks.com/transitioning-gradients/
you may use pseudo-elements like ::after and/or ::before to achieve the desired behavior.

CSS background (gradient) transition not working

You can use @property to animate gradient percent and color.
But it's not supported by firefox.
@property --p {
  syntax: "<percentage>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 100%;
}
@property --c {
  syntax: "<color>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: black;
}
.navbar {
  --p: 100%;
  --c: black;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, var(--c) var(--p), transparent); /* Start with a black background */
  transition: --p 0.5s, --c 0.5s; /* Smooth transition for background */
}
.navbar.scrolled {
  --p: 70%;
  --c: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}



window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
  const scrollToTopBtn = document.getElementById("scrollToTopBtn");
  const img = scrollToTopBtn.querySelector("img");

  // Handle navbar background transition
  if (window.pageYOffset > 21) {
    navbar.classList.add("scrolled");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("scrolled");
  }
});
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: 2000px; /* For demonstration purposes */
}
@property --p {
  syntax: "<percentage>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 100%;
}
@property --c {
  syntax: "<color>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: black;
}
.navbar {
  --p: 100%;
  --c: black;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* For Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 21px; /* Sets the navbar 21px from the top */
  width: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, var(--c) var(--p), transparent); /* Start with a black background */
  transition: --p 0.5s, --c 0.5s; /* Smooth transition for background */
  z-index: 1050;
}
.navbar.scrolled {
  --p: 70%;
  --c: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55);
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: #fff; /* Ensure this is white */
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-nav .nav-link.show {
  color: turquoise;
}
.navbar-nav {
  flex-direction: row !important; /* Ensures navbar items are in a row */
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute !important; /* Ensures dropdown opens as an overlay */
}
.nav-link {
  color: white !important; /* Customize color as needed */
}
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* Inline display */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; /* This ensures vertical alignment is centered */
  width: 100%; /* Ensures the navbar takes full width */
}
.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allows items to wrap in smaller screens */
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment */
  justify-content: space-between; /* Horizontal spacing */
  width: 100vw;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: column; /* Stack the links vertically on small screens */
  }
  .nav-link {
    padding: 0px 30px; /* Adjust padding for smaller screens */
    text-align: center; /* Center-align the text */
  }
}
.scroll-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
.scroll-to-top:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
.scroll-to-top img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
}
.scroll-to-top:hover img {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
#scrollToTopBtn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  z-index: 1000; /* Make sure it's above other content */
  outline: none;
}
#scrollToTopBtn img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Navbar Scroll Effect</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
              href="#drawings"
              id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
              role="button"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-expanded="false">
              Drawings
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drawing 1</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drawing 2</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drawing 3</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drawing 4</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drawing 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <button id="scrollToTopBtn" onclick="window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});">
      <img
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Yin_yang.svg/1024px-Yin_yang.svg.png" alt="Go to top" />
    </button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




this is great, but would there be a cross browser solution?
